# Count Number of Items Per Client and List these Items

Tags: sql

I have a relation in my assignment:

```
File (fid, fname, description, status, cname, lname)
```

The whole DB is a law firm and fid represent file ID, cname - client name, lname - lawyer name. The rest is irrelevant at the moment.

What I want to do is:

```
Find a client who has only 1 file and return the file and the client name.
```

I have no problem finding which client it is:

```
select file.cname, count(fid), 
from file
group by cname
having count(fid)=1
```

However if I add fid to this query I get a bad result.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select file.cname, count(fid), max(fid) 
from file
group by cname
having count(fid)=1
```

Comment: Upvoted because your last name is coincidentally the name of the school where @Gordon lectures.

Comment: Counting count=2 is another matter! Give it a try! If you can't figure it out, post what you've tried as a new question and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one value, then you can use `min()` or `max()` to get it:

```
select f.cname, min(f.fid) as fid
from file f
group by f.cname
having count(f.fid) = 1;
```

You don't need to specify the `count()` in the `select` in order to use it in the `having` clause (in most databases . . . there are exceptions, but I doubt you are using Hive).

Comment: @Alan . . . That would be a different question, and you should ask it as a question and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Alan if you want to select clients with count =2, 3, etc. you can use the query below and just adjust the number in the last line:

```
SELECT file.cname, file.fname
FROM file
WHERE file.cname IN
(SELECT file.cname
FROM file
GROUP BY file.cname
HAVING COUNT(fid) = 2);
```